# Would `git remote add --mirror=fetch` make same repo with `git clone --mirror`?

Tags: git, concurrency, git-clone, mirror, git-mirror

If I want to replicate a repo, I use this.

```
git clone --mirror $SRC $DST
```

But this command requires no repo exist at `$DST`. It's generally okay but if I want to issue Git commands concurrently from multiple processes, it may cause some race condition as no lockable file object exists before executing the command.

If I just want to skip existence test for `$DST`, I think I can do

```
mkdir -p $DST
cd $DST
git init --bare 
git remote add origin --mirror-=fetch $SRC 2>/dev/null || true
git remote update
```

Would this make exactly same repo with `git clone --mirror $SRC $DST`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [test done for a `git clone --mirror`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d98273ba77e1ab9ec755576bc86c716a97bf59d7/t/t5601-clone.sh#L108-L116), you would see a mirror clone is one with:

- a `fetch` refspec set to `+refs/*:refs/*`
- a `git config --bool remote.origin.mirror` set to true

If those conditions are met after your git remote commands, then yes, that would be equivalent to a mirror clone.

---

> So, if I run `git remote add --mirror=fetch && git fetch --all`, is it the same with "git clone --mirror"?

Running `git remote add --mirror=fetch && git fetch --all` after initializing a bare repository is *almost* the same as `git clone --mirror`.
But not quite.

When you use `git remote add --mirror=fetch`, Git configures the fetch refspec to `+refs/*:refs/*`, which does indeed mirror the behavior of `git clone --mirror` in terms of fetching all branches, tags, and other references from the source repository. And by executing `git fetch --all` following the remote addition, you are instructing Git to fetch from all remotes, which, in this context, means fetching all data from the source repository you have just added.

`git clone --mirror` automatically sets the configuration `remote.<remote>.mirror` to `true`. That configuration is essential for the repository to be treated as a true mirror, affecting not just fetch operations **but also push behaviors**. It makes sure the repository can serve as a complete mirror for both fetching and pushing changes.

That means that, while `git remote add --mirror=fetch && git fetch --all` successfully mirrors the content of the source repository into your local repository, to achieve complete equivalence with `git clone --mirror`, you need to manually set the `remote.<remote>.mirror` configuration:

```bash
git config --bool remote.origin.mirror true
```

Comment: So, if I run `git remote add --mirror=fetch && git fetch --all`, is it same with "git clone --mirror"? @vonc

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Almost. See my edited answer.